# How to search in several tables and show up only one of them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three mysql tables that are connected. I want to search with several keywords in all three but only show information from AREAS. For instance, if someone search for 'name1' I want to show the info found in the row for area nr 2 in the table AREAS.

```
+---------+--+-----------------+--+--------------------------+
| AREAS   |  | RINGS           |  | RINGSLOT                 |
+---------+--+-----------------+--+--------------------------+
| ID | nr |  | areanr | ringnr |  | ringnr | slot | slotname |
+----+----+--+--------+--------+--+--------+------+----------+
| 5  | 1  |  | 2      | 14     |  | 14     | 0    | name1    |
+----+----+--+--------+--------+--+--------+------+----------+
| 6  | 2  |  |        |        |  | 14     | 1    | name2    |
+----+----+--+--------+--------+--+--------+------+----------+
| 7  | 3  |  |        |        |  | 14     | 3    | name 3   |
+----+----+--+--------+--------+--+--------+------+----------+
```

So far I've tried with all kinds of FOR-loops without any success but think I got the query right, I just don't know how to process the info from here?

```
mysql_query("(SELECT * 'area' as type FROM areas WHERE nr LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%') 
       UNION
       (SELECT * 'ring' as type FROM rings WHERE ringnr LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%') 
       UNION
       (SELECT ring, namn 'slot' as type FROM ringslot WHERE slotname LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%')";
```

Comment: Select ar.* from area ar LEFT JOIN rings rn ON ar.nr = rn.areanr LEFT JOIN ringslot rs ON fn.ringnr = rs.ringnr WHERE rs.slotname LIKE %$keyword%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with joins, by showing up only the columns from `AREAS` table:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM areas A
LEFT JOIN RINGS r
 ON(A.nr = r.areanr)
LEFT JOIN RINGSLOT rs
 ON(r.ringnr = rs.ringnr)
WHERE r.slotname LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
   OR rs.ringnr LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
   OR A.nr LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'"
```

Comment: I tried using your query but I only get Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. I should say that searching for area numbers or ring numbers only should give exact result so I changed '%" . $keyword . "%' to '$keyword' for rs.ringnr and A.nr but that shouldn't cause this.

Comment: Change it from `LIKE` to `=` then.

Comment: Oh found it! should be `WHERE r.ringnr LIKE` and `OR rs.slotname LIKE`. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. This doesn't seem to work if you search for an area that has no rings. Interesting is also that if you search for slotname that works just fine and only one area shows. If you search for ring number or area number the area shows up 10 times.. There is 10 ringslots for every ring but I don't how that can affect the query I'm using..

Comment: I solved the issue with not showing areas that hasn't got a ring connected by using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information at the start. Yes, `LEFT JOIN` sounds like what you need.. is it working now? @KingleyMosso

Comment: I still get ten results when I search for area numbers or ring numbers. I'm guessing one for each ringslot, but I don't know how to get rid of that.

Comment: Just use distinct .. `SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM..` @KingleyMosso